# Pass Google Places lat and lng values from JavaScript on webpage to Django

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, google-places-api, get-request

I've used the Google Places API to put a map with a search box on an HTML page of my project. I want the following to happen: when someone searches a location, the coordinates (lat/lng) of the selected location are passed to the server. After this, I want to extract all entries of my Listing model (containing locations with their lat and lng) that are within a certain radius of the selected location, and pass back the lat/lng values to be displayed as markers on the map.

I've pretty much copied the JavaScript from the Google example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox, and I understand that this is the relevant section for extracting the lat/lng:

```
        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));
```

From looking at other answers on here, it seems that the way to get the lat and lng is as follows:

```
var lat = place.geometry.location.lat();
var lng = place.geometry.location.lng();
```

Should I just place these variables below the above block of code? And how do I go about sending them to the server (if that is what I need to do)? Some answers to vaguely similar questions seem to suggest including an invisible form that is submitted with POST, and others mention AJAX, but I'm very new to this (and haven't dealt with JavaScript before) so I don't know what would work best for this application, nor how to implement them.

Thanks in anticipation!